# How can I detect the state of Content at View startup?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Lets assume I have created my own custom view for a Link content type. When the user adds a 2sxc Content app to a Pane, then picks the Content Type (Link) then my custom View, when it first starts up, how can I detect that a) the View does not use a Demo item vs. b) the View uses a demo item and is showing the Demo item vs. c) its not the first time and there is a real user added Content (Entity) in place?

I have done stuff like this for the a) case:

```
var link = AsDynamic(Data["Default"]).First();
```

then checked if it was null, but it looks like my View code never executes and instead I just see, "No demo item exists for the selected template."

If I do assign a demo, is there a more elegant way to know that the Entity I am handed as Content.First() or Data["Default"]).First() is a Demo item and now a user created Entity? Currently I am hard-coding the EntityId in the template and testing for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IsDemoItem property added in 2sxc 10.06

[Dynamic Entity](https://docs.2sxc.org/articles/dynamic-entity.html)

Answer (score 0):

The template system does not render the template if there is no demo item (unless it's a template without a content-type). 
When we need this, we have two ways

1. give the demo item a unique value in one of the fields and check for that in the template
2. check the demo-item ID on GUID and check for that `(Content.EntityGuid == ...)`

Comment: So I guess this is really a feature request then. I doubt you will see it as a high priority, but it seems obvious that when the View is being presented with a demo item, that Entity should have a boolean IsDemo() property to inspect or something to that effect. I realize your way works and is a solution, but it is not intuitive and prone to users breaking things over time. Somewhere in your code you are choosing to output a demo item instead of a real one, seems like there is a simple opportunity to flag it in some way.

Comment: Agree. Please put a feature request up for this.

Comment: Note that https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1792 was updated with an extensive discussion, please contribute your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

If a Content Editor "Hides" the only Content Item, the anonymous user will then see a Demo Item where the item was. This is confusing and unexpected from the Content Editor's point of view (as well as the public/anonymous user). If anyone else runs in to it, here is the simple code snippet to add to the start of your view. Basically, if the current user is not logged in and the item to display is a demo item, exit the View w/o displaying anything.

```
  if(!Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    if(Content.IsDemoItem ?? false) {
      return;
    }
  }
```

Best to put it near the start of your first @{} Razor block.

Note: this will not throw an error in 2sxc prior to 10.6.x (because of the "?? false"), but it will not work either.