# How do I not display the demo item in an empty list?

Tags: 2sxc

I'm using the 2SXC Content module (using Razor templates) to build a list of items. In some cases, I want to let my content editors simply remove all of the items from the list and either show nothing at all, or show a custom message. Currently, in a basic set up, if the content editor removes all the items from the list, it will simply revert to showing the demo item as defined by the template.

For example, I have a list of "Sessions", and my content editors regularly add and remove sessions from this list. If there are no sessions, I want to let them simply remove all the sessions and then have the module either empty or show a message that says "There are no more sessions."

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is already version 14.x of 2sxc but seems like `IsDemoItem` is still not working. So seems like simplest workaround is simply mark demo item as not published and then it won't display in the list of items.
And `if` will help you display whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

This seem very similar to what I am trying to do. Check Daniel's [answer/discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720774/how-can-i-detect-the-state-of-content-at-view-startup).

What I like to do is use the EntityId of my Demo Item. So basically, I have code like this:

```
if (Content.EntityId == 2277) {
    // do stuff because the View is showing its Demo Item
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Jeremy. Your answer is good and it's great to see your question is requesting a feature change.

Comment: Note that https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1792 was updated with an extensive discussion, please contribute your opinions.